# Clickable HTML Dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html

i have dropdown menu like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_filter) :

```js
document.getElementById("example").addEventListener("click", denemeFunc);

function denemeFunc() {

  document.getElementById("searchBtn").innerText = ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?

}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
  <div id="example" runat="server">
    <a href="#About" data-toggle="About">About</a>
    <a href="#base" data-toggle="Base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog" data-toggle="Blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact" data-toggle="Contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
</div>
```

Here's my question : How can i catch the a tag's name when its clicked ? 
For example : I clicked the #About tag and i want to searchBtn's name become the About. How can i do this ?

Comment: how about add `event` to `addEventListener`? looks like - `document.getElementById("example").addEventListener("click", function(event) {console.log(event.target)})`, and from the target param you can take the href.

Comment: Where is `#searchBtn` in your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First receive the event object in the callback

```
function denemeFunc(evt) {
```

Then you can interrogate the delegated element that fired the event via `evt.target`

```
document.getElementById("searchBtn").innerText = evt.target.innerHTML;
```